# Finding the number of digits in LONG_LONG_MAX

Tags: c++11

I would like to safely minimize the buffer needed for the array when doing

```cxx
std::string integer_like_type::to_string(long long value){

    std::array<char, WHAT_DO_I_PUT_HERE? +1> buffer;

    int imGood = std::sprintf( buffer, "%d", value);
    std::assert( imGood >= 0 );
    return std::string( buffer );
}
```

"limits.h" is not helpful at all.

As I want it as a template parameter.

I'm not asking for

```
while ( value/=10 ){ digits++; }
```

solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [std::numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) to query information about numeric types at compile time. Your are looking to [max_digits10](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10):

```
std::array<char, std::numeric_limits<long long>::max_digits10 + 1> buffer;
```

Answer (score 2):

Take the number you want to find the number of digits in, then divide by ten in a loop until the result is zero.

---

In your case though, you are duplicating functionality already *in* the standard C++ library, and it's aptly named the same even: [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: I would prefer it as my template parameter. I'd even go with log if were for brevity.

Comment: std::to_string is an almost perfect solution solution.  I actually want the char array. istringstream does not suit my real scenario. I made a mistake in my sscce. Also I did not know about std::to_string.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a common way is to do

```
ceil(log10(LLONG_MAX)) + 1;
```

note this is runtime so probably not the best answer, making a compile time macro is probably a better idea.

Comment: A macro would probably be even worse, but Joachim and nosid both provided solid solutions to my predicament.

Comment: I don't see how a macro would be worse, but yes nosid's answer is the best regarding finding digit count if you're using C++.